# ssh from vagrant and my username

Tags: ssh, vagrant, vagrantfile

I'd like to have access to ssh keys on a vagrant box so that I can access other hosts from there.  I do this

```
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
   config.ssh.forward_agent = true
end
```

and this in ~/.ssh/config

```
Host 127.0.0.1
  ForwardAgent yes
```

(note to future generations: not `localhost`), then `vagrant reload`.  Good.

```
╭╴ (master *$%=)╶╮
╰ jeff@birdsong:analytics $ vagrant ssh
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-101-generic x86_64)
[...]
[T] ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~ $ ssh-add -l
[...we have identities!...]
[T] ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~
```

But now I still have to explicitly use my username, since user `vagrant` is not what I want when I jump to other worlds through ssh.  I'd like to script this and share the scripts within my team, so just typing my name isn't the answer.

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -L 1234:host.example.com:1234 jeff@some.host.somewhere
```

We could all agree to set an environment variable, like for me `VAGRANT_SSH_USER=jeff` and then use that in our scripts.  But perhaps there is a better way that doesn't require everyone to set environment variables?

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -L 1234:host.example.com:1234 $VAGRANT_SSH_USER@some.host.somewhere
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass $USER into your ssh script. VAGRANT_SSH_USER=$USER.

hope this helps